# Transition probability conditioned on the future state and the present state of a Markov process

Tags: markov-process

Consider a process that takes state $X_{t-1}$ to $X_t$. Let us also assume that the process is Markovian. Therefore,

$$P(X_t | X_{t-1}, X_{t-2}, X_{t-3}, ...) = P(X_t | X_{t-1}).$$

My question is whether the Markovian property also implies

$$P(X_t | X_{t-1}, X_{t+n}) = P(X_t | X_{t-1})$$

where $n>0$?